# Incorrect Consecutive days visit count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I always check out Askubuntu and WordPress Answers several times a day. I have been a consecutive visitor of both for 59 days now. MY profile over at WPA shows it right but AskUbuntu is not. How can it go out of sync when WPA worked absolutely fine.

I have both of them pinned in my Firefox 4 and there is no way this could have happened. I was hoping to go for the 100 days consecutive badge. Sad! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it definitely doesn't think you visited on the 29th.

One thing to mention is that Firefox does cache pages even between loads. I know this because I build websites and for testing I run a server that needs manually launching. I can view the testing site in Firefox and then restart the computer, load Firefox and it'll show the testing site (even though the server isn't running) from cache.

I suggest something like that happened on the 29th and you didn't actually load any new pages. I'll let Jeff comment but I think it's more likely that your browser just didn't request a page on that day than the server somehow not logging your activity.

I've also checked your activity log which shows nothing for the 29th. If you want your uptime to be accountable, make sure you do something that leaves a date trail (post, comment, vote, flag, etc).

Comment: I am sure I visited it but may be it was the browser issue. I was online for a small time and I checked out the frontpage for any interesting questions. Seems like that is the case.

Comment: Well that's probably explained by Jeff's answer in jgbelacqua's first link ['homepage style pages, don't count as "access"'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485).

Comment: oh that makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @ash yep it has to be a "deep" link visit

Comment: Yeah got it now! Earning just for the sake of it is not worth it and I will earn it with time anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

See :

[Consecutive Days Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97) .

[Do we need to just visit or participate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/enthusiast-fanatic-badge-do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate)

[What are the exact requirements for the enthusiast badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge)

[Does visiting chat count towards enthusiast and fanatic badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63472/does-visiting-chat-count-towards-enthusiast-and-fanatic)