# Page shows 3 consecutive days on askubuntu. This is incorrect. Why?

Tags: support

I have looked at both

1)  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1196/incorrect-consecutive-days-visit-count

and

2) [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

But neither addresses my issue.

My activity log clearly shows activity for far more consecutive days of work than is being reported. Can anyone explain this to me?  This isn't about a lack of participation either. Please see my [log](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek?tab=activity).

Comment: You missed Wednesday the second, according to your profile.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the missed day is related to timezone differences between askubuntu.com and here.

Comment: Yup, that's probably it. All of SE runs on UTC time, which can get tricky. I know the SE day resets around 5:00 PM my time.