# incorrect (4) consecutive days count while I visit this page every day

Tags: support

I visit the AskUbuntu-page every day and browse trough the questions. I open questions and mostly browse till page 4. I don't really understand how my counter shows only 4 days. Please can anyone tell me why this doesn't count? Thank you  very much.

Comment: Hmm the counter has been adjusted recently and might be buggy. You only need to visit the site for it to theoretically "count".

Comment: The counter looks at dates in UTC rather than local time. Depending on when you visit the site, there may have been a period of time greater than 24 hours where you did not visit that happened to fall within 0:00 ~ 23:59:59 UTC. This has bitten me a few times ... 

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies and time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page shows 3 consecutive days on askubuntu. This is incorrect. Why?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10465/page-shows-3-consecutive-days-on-askubuntu-this-is-incorrect-why)